# How to output array in 2 columns

Tags: angularjs

I have array with object's and I need to output this array in 2 column's. I tried to use filter, ng-switch-when. But always array output's in 1 col. There is my array: [image]

Here is my last try outputting with ng-switch-when:

```
<div ng-repeat="date in allDates">
                <div ng-switch="date.invited_date">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td ng-switch-when="1">{{date.project_name}}</td>
                            <td ng-switch-when="0">{{date.project_name}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Actual result is: [image]

But i need to separate them by invited_date in 2 column's how can I do it?

I can do it in 2 tables, but then if project name will be long it will ruin structure 
[image]

Comment: Use a table inside the td's

Answer (score 0):

You cant show in two rows with single iteration , try as two iteration

```
 <div ng-repeat="date in allDates">
            <div ng-switch="date.invited_date">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-switch-when="1">{{date.project_name}}</td>

                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>

     <div ng-repeat="date in allDates">
            <div ng-switch="date.invited_date">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>

                        <td ng-switch-when="0">{{date.project_name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Yes I did it like that, but then if project name will be long it will ruin structure, like on last screenshot. Problem is that they are independant